# Getting Xml problem from TCP/IP connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, tcp, feed

I am working on an application where i have to get some feeds from the server. now when i start the application, i send a request for login and get schedule, in response it gives me a string "VALID" and then it gives me some xml for schedule. Now most of times it gives me the string in more then one response and also mix two xmls.

Infect it gives me some lines of an xml "CHANGES" and then start giving my required xml "SCHEDULE" and at the end it completes the "CHANGES" xml. I don't need "CHANGES" xml.

its look is like

```
<Changes>
<Schedule>
</Schedule>
</Changes>
```

So what should I do to get just "Schedule" xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by get all that responses on server side and then I bind them and then hosted them on a server and fetch that xmls with the help of a url

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to read contents of Schedule tag ().
To read that You can NSXMLParser.
[see this tutorial](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html)

and chk NSXMLParserDelegate methods

Comment: implement at least 2 delegate methods didstartelement and foundCharacters. Now you can read data in this ways, suppose you have total three tags in your xml file <element>, <element1> and <element2> and you want data from element tag only. In didstartelement check the current element if it is "element" set a flag(flag=1 or anything else) now check flag in foundCharacters method if(flag==1) store the string in an array or append it to a string(whatever you want to do).